# Auto refresh a page every time after it loads

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, web, refresh

I'm looking for a script which loads a URL and auto refreshes it as soon as it's completely loads.
Timer wont work, as the load time of page will be different every time.

```
 window.onload = function () {window.location.reload()}
```

Please help me to modify this script to be able to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"> //add this in head tag of that page to refresh every 1 second

Comment: I was looking for a script that reloads a web page as soon as it completes loading..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload();}, 6000);
```

Comment: This will reload the page every 6 seconds

Comment: Thanks for help, But I want it to refresh as soon as URL link loads. so the timing will be different every time. 6 seconds won't work, could we set it to reload as soon as web page loads?